# Wrong symbols linked. Why?

Tags: c++

C++ translator seems uses correct declared `struct`s of the same name, but then linker mismatches them without any warning or error! And this also leads to UB, because at least inappropriate ctor/dtor are used for the memory region.

Here is minimal sandbox code. Each `struct Test` should be treated as some internal non-public structure used only in one own .cpp file.

**file1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void someFunc();


struct Test
{
    Test() { std::cout << "1  "; }
    ~Test() { std::cout << "~1" << std::endl; }
};


int main()
{
    {
        Test test;
    }

    someFunc();

    return 0;
}
```

**file2.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
    Test() { std::cout << "2  "; }
    ~Test() { std::cout << "~2" << std::endl; }
};

void someFunc() {
    Test test;
}
```

*(Downloadable and buildable CMake-project just in case: https://file.io/dzafv409B2t0)*

Output will be:

```
1  ~1
1  ~1
```

So, I expected:

- Successful build with output: `1 ~1   2 ~2`
- Or failed build with `multiple definition` error

Yes, I can resolve the problem if:

- Rename the struct
- Put the struct into anonymous namespace - force internal linkage

...but this doesn't answer the main question:

- Why linker behaves so? Why does it silently links to first available matching symbol (among several) instead of reporting multiple definition error?

---

**Update:** As I understood, this mechanism allows to include header with class declaration (with inline code) into several different source files without multiple definition problem.

Comment: if this caused a multiple definition error you wouldn't be able to define structures in header files

Comment: @AlanBirtles, Ok, now I see. Thank you

Comment: yes but the behaviour would be the same if `Test` was defined in a header, headers are just effectively copy and pasted into your cpp file

Comment: The local `struct Test` in each file should be surrounded in a `namespace {` ... `}`.  The anonymous namespace will make each of those things local to the translation unit.